# SFDX LWC Deploy

Tags: lightning-web-components

I Am getting this error in my VSC in Problems. Also Get an red dot next that file promting Contains Emphasized Items

Failed to save Lightning Component Resource [lwc/lwcLoanValuesInput/lwcLoanValuesInput.css] of Lightning Component Bundle [lwcLoanValuesInput]. Error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION

Comment: Can you include a screenshot?  Have you been able to deploy LWC components before this?

Comment: Your `lwcLoanValuesInput.css` file may be empty. Could you please post your `.css` file

Comment: I have solved the issue. It was not empty but rather a permission issue. Thanks

Comment: Which permission was missing?